# Spawn EACCES in demeteorizer

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to demeteorizer the meteor app with demeteorizer command
 it show error like 
`$demeteorizer -o ../demeterialize/`

> Demeteorizing application...
>   Error: spawn EACCES
>      at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)

Comment: Please review: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - specifically the section on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).